# Quantum Angular Momentum Covariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, covariance

The angular momentum is quantified in Quantum Mechanics, it can only take multiples of $\hbar$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Quantization

The previous statement seems to apply to any inertial reference system in which the measured particle is measured; however, the angular momentum is a quantity that transforms covariantly as a tensor together with the dynamic mass moment **N**=m**x**-t**p** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum

According to this transformation, the momentum cannot be 1 ($\hbar$) in all the systems, even if the dynamic mass moment is zero because we measure the particle from its center of mass.

My question, therefore is, how does the quantum angular momentum transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining the angular momentum into a 4-vector which changes covariantly under the full group of Lorentz transformations, however, the core of what is confusing you does not require this.  In what follows I will simplify the question to only an angular momentum vector $L^i$ which transforms covariantly under the usual three dimensional rotations.  Here the same confusion should exist without the need to involve special relativity.

The historical path quantum theory took was filled with many false starts and dead ends.  Putting philosophical discussion about the interpretation of quantum mechanics aside; when the dust settled there was a relatively well agreed upon procedure for obtaining a quantum mechanical theory from a classical one which we call "quantization".  The main idea of this is that particle states are no longer represented by phase space coordinates (x,p), but rather by an element $|\psi\rangle$ of a vector space $\mathcal{H}$.  Observable quantities, like position, momentum, or anything that was classically defined as a function of them (such as angular momentum) are now represented by operators which act on the vector space.  When you observe these quantities in an ideal setting, you will obtain one of the eigenvalues of that operator probabilistically, with the probability distribution determined by the state $|\psi\rangle$ which the particle was in.

Now, it so happens that the operator corresponding to angular momentum has finitely many distinct eigenvalues and this is what we mean when we say that it is quantized: you can only ever measure one of those  discrete values.  When we do a coordinate rotation $R$ it will now act on the state vector in a unitary representation $U(R)$ (unitary is necessary to make sure the probability of measuring anything remains 1):
$$
|\psi\rangle\rightarrow U(R)|\psi\rangle\equiv|\psi\rangle_R.
$$
This can alternatively be viewed as an action on the spaces operators such as the "vector of angular momentum operators" $\hat{L}^i$ as:
$$
\hat{L}^i\rightarrow U(R)^\dagger \hat{L}^i U(R)
$$

These will still look like the usual continuous transformations on vectors but now in the context of the operators $\hat{L}^i$.  But at the end of the day, this transformation will not change the operators eigenvalues, so you can only ever measure one of the same discrete set of angular momenta eigenvalues, with the probability of measuring a certain value depending on the state $|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see that the reason why angular momentum is quantizied is because it is an operator whose eigenvalues can take only discrete values.

Comment: I get that the average momentum is a continuous quantity, calculated with the probabilities of each eigenvalue, but each eigenvalue must take discrete values.

Comment: Are you asking for further clarification?

Comment: No, it seems clear to me, thank you @Wintermute